# Display the values from different column in one column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to display the values of unique from 3 columns or i would like to say i want to know the status of the product if it is listed in any 3 of countries in the table.

1. pls display the unique of D,F & H in K and display if any values corresponding to D,F & H in "L".

OR

2. when we enter a product from col D,F & H in col K .. Col L must display the status of that product.

Hope u understand what i want.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D_Vv_lSrBdRgKFQfPt8IIxrgMoB_ca6yyZwkDymvRLQ/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following formula

```
=QUERY({C4:D11;E4:F11;G4:H11}, "where Col2 is not null")
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)

Using `{C4:D11;E4:F11;G4:H11}` we create an array of stacked ranges one on top of the other.
*(Please adjust ranges to your needs)*

Answer (score 0):

From the information you provided, I could think of using [CONCATENATE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094123?hl=en) to display the value from these country rows if one is filled and the rest are empty.

You could use the following formula and then expand below:

```
=CONCATENATE(D4,F4,H4,K4)
```

Here is an image demonstrating the result of this. Let me know  if this was what you were aiming for:

[image]

Comment: will u pls perform the action in that shared spreadsheet ?? thank you

Comment: thats not what i want.. what i want is when i type a product name in col J, col L must display its status

Comment: i put a formula in K4.but it takes only the value from C:D try to expand that formula. then it will work. if the product in C & E are same then it will take only C. thats the problem